# Expressing the language of squares as a concatenation of two languages

Tags: formal-languages, word-combinatorics

Can the language $L = \{ vv : v \in \Sigma^* \}$ be expressed as the concatenation of two nontrivial languages? (A language is nontrivial if it differs from $\{\epsilon\}$.)

Comment: Also I found that non trivial language simply means non empty language {epsilon} is the trivial language

Comment: @Shannu In this exercise it makes sense to forbid $\{\epsilon\}$. Note, however, that $\{\epsilon\}$ is *not* the empty language; the empty language is $\emptyset$. Rather, $\{\epsilon\}$ is the language consisting of the empty *word*.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: I tried solving it using turing machine. We can construct a turing machine for vv. Assuming there are languages L1 and L2 such that L=L1L2. Since turing recognizable language is closed under concatenation so we can say that L can be represented as L=L1L2. I am not sure though if it is correct approach

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on $|\Sigma|$. If $\Sigma$ contains a single letter then $L = (\Sigma\Sigma)^*(\Sigma\Sigma)^*$ can be written as a concatenation of two nontrivial languages.

Conversely, suppose that $|\Sigma| > 1$, say $a,b \in \Sigma$. Since $\epsilon \in L$, necessarily $\epsilon \in L_1,L_2$. This implies that all words in $L_1,L_2$ are squares, and in particular $a \notin L_1,L_2$. Since $aa \in L$, we must have $aa \in L_1$ or $aa \in L_2$. Without loss of generality, assume that $aa \in L_1$. We similarly get that $bb \in L_1$ or $bb \in L_2$. Since $aabb \notin L$, we must have $bb \in L_1$. Since $L_2 \neq \{\epsilon\}$, it must contain some non-empty word $w$. Hence both $aaw$ and $bbw$ are squares. However, this is impossible (why?), and we reach a contradiction.